# LongStream filtering

Tags: java, java-stream

I have two Java LongStreams and I want to remove values which are present in one stream from the other.

```
LongStream stream 1 = ...
LongStream stream 2 = ...

stream2  = stream2.filter(e-> stream1.contains(e));
```

The LongStream does not have a contains method and I dont know how to use anyMatch in this case because the value to be checked is coming from another stream and is not in a variable or constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot search in the Stream as long as Stream is an unfinished set of pipelines, i.e. operations. It makes no sense to compare it with such Stream.

The next thing that seems odd to me is probably a typo. I assume you want to search in the `stream1` instead of `stream2`, hence:

```
stream2 = stream2.filter(e -> stream1.contains(e));
```

The only way is to compare a `LongStream` with a collection which is optimized for such search. I assume you want to continue the `stream1` after you perform the search, so perform these steps:

1. Close `stream1` converting it to a `List<Long> list1`.
2. Perform the search in `stream2` using `list1` from `stream1`.
3. Open `stream1` again for further processing.

```
LongStream stream1 = ...
LongStream stream2 = ...

List<Long> list1 = stream1.boxed()                       // list1 from stream1 ..
                          .collect(Collectors.toList()); // .. which also closes stream1

stream2  = stream2.filter(list1::contains);              // perform search

stream1 = list1.stream().mapToLong(l -> l);              // open stream1 as LongStream
```

**Edit:** Use `Set` for better performance as @[fps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1876620/fps) suggests in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65091723/3764965).

Answer (score 3):

You could collect to a `Set` and use `contains`:

```
LongStream stream1 = ...
LongStream stream2 = ...

Set<Long> set1 = stream1.boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());

stream2 = stream2.filter(set1::contains);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use streams at all?

Collections have the [`retainAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) method, that does just what you need, if i am not mistaken...
(Or `removeAll(Collection)` just a bit above...)